# Проверка обязательного наличия команды в командной строке Java

Tags: java, валидация, командная-строка

Пишу приложение командной строки, в которм каждый элемент массива String[] args, представляется как ключ=значение. Например `--file=simple.txt add --name=John --surname=Doe --age=20 --email=john@doe.com`
Строка парсится с помощью Map<> и, каждый ключ (file, add, name  и т.д.) является командой. Правильность написания этой команды я проверяю через Перечисление, вот так:

```
public enum CommandsNameValidator {
FILE("file"),
ADD("add"),
A("a"),
FIND("find"),
F("f"),
REPLACE("replace"),
R("r"),
VIEW("view"),
V("v"),
HELP("help"),
H("h"),
CLEAR("clear"),
C("c"),
NAME("name"),
N("n"),
SURNAME("surname"),
S("s"),
AGE("age"),
EMAIL("email"),
E("e"),
ID("id"),
FROM("from"),
TO("to");

private final String value;

CommandsNameValidator(String value){
    this.value = value;
}

public static CommandsNameValidator fromString(String s) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return Arrays.stream(CommandsNameValidator.values())
            .filter(v -> v.value.equals(s))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("unknown command: " + s));
}}
```

Не каждая из команд всегда нужна. Скажем, команда "file" - нужна всегда, иначе не будет программе понятно куда сохранять, где искать и пр... Исполняющая команда (add, find и пр.) - тоже всегда нужна, но только одна из них, - не все сразу. А вот остальные - по необходимости. Например, если нужно просмотреть содержимое файла, достаточно использовать только команду "view" (`--file=simple.txt view`)
Вопрос в следующем, - как правильно организовать проверку обязательна команда или нет?

Comment: Раз вы завели enum, можете туда второе поле добавить - `boolean isRequired` и искать во входной строке, чтобы были все required параметры, а если какого-то не нашли, то кидайте ошибку.

Comment: @ iksuy Да, спасибо. Это стоит попробовать... Вот только, как я говорил в своем вопросе, не все параметры обязательны безусловно, встречаются ситуации, когда не все они нужны...

Answer (score 1):

Человечество уже решило эту проблему. Посмотрите в сторону готовых решений, например [picocli](https://picocli.info/). На крайний случай, можете подсмотреть, как это сделано у них, благо код открыт.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) поможет вам. Тут есть небольшая статья на русском [Работа с commons-cli 1.2](https://habr.com/post/123360/), а здесь на английском [Usage Scenarios](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html)